# Unable to set margin between buttons

Tags: reactjs, class, materialize, margin

I'm new to the React and can't figure out why css rules cannot be applied to my button styling.

I have a button with `className="btn yellow"` and another button placed next to it with the class`"bnt red"` for update and delete actions. I need to make margin between them.

```
<button className="btn yellow">Update</button>
<button className="btn red btnmargin">Delete</button>
```

I have defined the class called `btnmargin` with `margin-left:10px` and it's not working.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

In regular HTML we could just add a space, just like you add space between words in a sentence. But that won’t work in React JSX. The space will be gone when the view renders in the browser.